# Incrementar en uno mayor valor de una tabla SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

El objetivo que intento conseguir con la consulta que describiré a continuación es seleccionar el mayor valor del campo `POSITION` e incrementarlo en uno para asignarselo a aquellos campos que tienen valor cero.

```
UPDATE ps_category SET POSITION = ((SELECT POSITION, FROM ps_category ORDER BY POSITION DESC LIMIT 1 ) + 1) WHERE POSITION = 0
```

Primero empecé realizando consultas más simples para posteriormente conseguir una consulta más compleja

- `SELECT * FROM ps_category WHERE POSITION = 0`
- `SELECT POSITION, FROM ps_category ORDER BY POSITION DESC LIMIT 1`

Una vez construida la consulta, arreglé problemas de sintaxis quedando de la siguiente forma

```
UPDATE ps_category p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(POSITION) + 1 new_position FROM ps_category) m
SET p.POSITION = m.new_position
WHERE p.POSITION = 0
```

De esta manera al ejecutarse la consulta reemplaza todos los registros de `POSITION` con valor cero por el mayor valor encontrado en la tabla más uno.

El problema es que por ejemplo si el mayor valor que se encuentra en la tabla es diez y existen tres registros con valor `POSITION` cero les ha de poner los siguientes valores: once, doce y trece. En cambio actualmente por cómo está formada la consulta asignaría un valor de once a todos los registros con valor cero

---

INFORMACIÓN RELACIONADA CON TABLAS

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_category` (
`id_category` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_parent` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_shop_default` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`level_depth` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nleft` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nright` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`active` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`date_upd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`position` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_root_category` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_category`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `category_parent` (`id_parent`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `nleftrightactive` (`nleft`, `nright`, `active`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `level_depth` (`level_depth`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `nright` (`nright`) USING BTREE,
 INDEX `activenleft` (`active`, `nleft`) USING BTREE,
```

### [image: Estructura de tabla con información]

OTRA INFORMACIÓN DE UTILIDAD

- Version: 5.7.31-log
- Engine: InnoDB;
- MySQLController: DbPDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El SQL ejecutará siempre solamente una vez la consulta para obtener el mayor valor almacenado en `position`.

Tomando este valor, puedes utilizar una *variable* que se va incrementando registro a registro, para sumar este valor al obtenido del `max(position`), de manera que se vaya creando un consecutivo mientras se ejecuta la consulta.

En el ejemplo, la variable se llama `@rownum` y se inicializa con valor de `0` en el nuevo `cross join` que he agregado, y el valor obtenido de `max(position)` se encuentra en el campo `base_position` de `m`. Luego, con cada registro que se procese, irá incrementándose en uno y ese valor se sumará a `base_position`.

```
update ps_category p
       cross join (select max(position) base_position FROM ps_category) m
       cross join (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
   set p.POSITION = m.base_position + (@rownum := @rownum + 1)
 where p.POSITION = 0;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación!

Comment: @naumb, me alegra ser de ayuda. Me he percatado que tienes publicadas más de 30 preguntas, muchas de ellas tienen respuestas, pero solo unas pocas tienen una respuesta marcada como _aceptada_. Esta es una de las características que diferencia a StackOverflow de los antiguos sistemas de foros, y es de mucha utilidad para quienes, en el futuro, lleguen a alguna de tus preguntas en una búsqueda o investigación, pues podrán ver con claridad si hay una respuesta que te ayudó a resolver el problema.

Comment: Es cierto que aceptar una respuesta, además de lo mencionado, le da cierta reputación a quien respondió de manera acertada (+15), pero si te pido que aceptes más respuestas no es porque yo en particular busque esa reputación, sino realmente por lo que he mencionado al inicio. Un saludo.

Comment: Te doy toda la razón en eso, suelo votar en positivo cuando encuentro una pregunta que me ha solucionado el problema pero se me despista marcarla como aceptada muchas veces. Esta al menos ya está lista!

Comment: Gracias, igual creo que debieras revisar las otras preguntas que has hecho y quizás puedas marcar otras respuestas también como aceptadas. De nuevo, un saludo!